# How to only keep line that start with a character and the line after

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a FASTA file that has intentionally some sequences with wrong header (i.e absence of `>`) and some with good header. The file is well-formatted in the sense that the nucleotidic sequence is in one line.

Example :

```
2865958
AACTACTACAG
>hCoV-19/2832832
ACTCGGGGGG
28328332
ATTCCCCG
>hCoV-19/2789877
ACTCGGCCC
```

And I want to only keep the sequence with a correct header (i.e line that starts with `>`) like this :

```
>hCoV-19/2832832
ACTCGGGGGG
>hCoV-19/2789877
ACTCGGCCC
```

I've tried various method for it ( sed, grep, awk ) but no proper result :

```
awk '/^>/ { ok=index($0,"hCoV")!=0;} {if(ok) print;}' combined_v4.fa > combined_v5.fa

sed -n '/^>.*hCoV/,/^>/ {/^>.*hCoV/p ; /^>/! p}' combined_v4.fa > combined_v5.fa

grep -w ">" -A 1 combined_v4.fa > combined_v5.fa
```

Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: How about `grep -A 1 '^>hCoV-'`

Comment: why the `-w` (=`--word-regexp`) switch for `grep`?

Answer (score 9):

Tell `grep` too look for lines starting with `>`, and include the line following it:

```
grep -A1 --no-group-separator '^>' combined_v4.fa > combined_v5.fa
```

In case your version of `grep` does not support `--no-group-separator`, try this:

```
grep -A1 '^>' combined_v4.fa | grep -v '^--$' > combined_v5.fa
```

Comment: A shame `--no-group-separator` hasn't made it to `man`. It's documented in `info grep invoking command-line context` , though.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way with sed:

```
sed -n '/^>/!d;N;p' file
```

Note that if the last line of input begins with ">", this will not print it.

With awk:

```
awk 'prev {print prev ORS $0; prev=""} /^>/ {prev=$0}' file
```

Wait until the line after ">" to print the two lines. Insead of a regex, `index()` could be used:

```
awk 'prev {print prev ORS $0; prev=""} index($0,">")==1 {prev=$0}' file
```

`^>` is a regular expression to match a string that begins with ">". `index($0,">")` returns the starting position of the string ">", which must to be equal to one (`...==1`) if the record starts with it.

To make sure it also has "hCoV":

```
sed -n '/^>/!d;/hCoV/!d;N;p' file
```

```
awk 'prev {print prev ORS $0; prev=""} /^>/ && /hCoV/ {prev=$0}' file
```

Comment: Or just `sed '/^>/!d;N'`. Then if the last line starts with `>`, whether it's printed will depend on the `sed` implementation and in the case of GNU `sed`, whether `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment or not.

Answer (score 3):

With awk, you could do:

```bsh
awk '/^>/ {c=2} c-- > 0' file
```

to print 2 lines when `>` is seen.

Comment: you could use `c&&c--` so it stops counting when c is 0 and so c can't wrap around if the input file is massive enough for the negative to become positive again. it's an edge condition for sure!

Answer (score 2):

I propose this, using GNU `sed`:

```bsh
# find the multiline pattern ^digits→ACGT
# and delete those lines
$ sed '/^[[:digit:]]\+$/,/^[ACGT]\+$/d' file 
>hCoV-19/2832832
ACTCGGGGGG
>hCoV-19/2789877
ACTCGGCCC
```

Comment: `\+` in a BRE might be specific to GNU sed.

Comment: @rowboat thanls, I added it to the answer.

Comment: The standard equivalent of GNU's `\+` is `\{1,\}`. Or you could use `+` with `-E` (soon standard, and more widely supported than `\+`).

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you can try:

```
awk 'f {print; f=0} /^>/ {print;f=1}' file
>hCoV-19/2832832
ACTCGGGGGG
>hCoV-19/2789877
ACTCGGCCC
```

- This excellent post can help you:

> "Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern